# Should I include .eot files in github repo

Tags: git, github

I am working on a project, and I have downloaded some `.eot` files and have them in `/fonts` directory.

My question is should I include those files in github repository?

I have opened one of them and it contains 2000+ lines of text.

Comment: What would be your reason for _not_ including them? Since they aren't text files, "lines of text" is not a meaningful measure (and if it was, 2000 lines would not be a large number), but maybe you're actually worried about file _size_ (measured in bytes)?

Comment: @IMSoP their file size is about `200KB`

Comment: @sp Kruten: .eot format is only supported by internet explorer. So you can safely ditch this format for modern browsers/apps. However, a rare use case might be the need for legacy support e.g. for very special embedded systems running on custom windows versions an supporting only ie capabilities